# keyListener "Enter" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

```
function checkId() {
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox").value;

  if (password == "superx") {
    return true;
  };

  alert("Not Allowed :(");

  return false;
};

function keyAdd() {
  passwordBox.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      checkId();
    }
  })
};
```

What's the problem in the second function?

Comment: Is your variable passwordBox defined?  And does your code call the keyAdd function?

Comment: ^... Also post any errors in your console.

Comment: sorry not working with this method and no errors in the console, you can try and you will see it is not working

Answer (score 0):

1) https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onkeypress.asp said : "***Note:*** The addEventListener() method is **not** supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions." try : "*object.onkeypress = function(){myScript};*" instead...

2)maybe you don't call "keyAdd()" at all...

Comment: sorry not working with this method and no errors in the console, you can try and you will see it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```js
<script>
 
function checkId() {

 var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox").value;
 if (password == "superx") {

  return true;

 }
  
 alert("Not Allowed :(");
  
 return false;
};



function keyAdd() {

passwordBox.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 13){

    checkId();

    }
})
};

 </script>
```

```html
 <input type="password" name="passwordBox" id="passwordBox" onkeypress="return keyAdd(event)"/>
```